# OneToOneFiled value not updated after using save() command

Tags: django

I'm trying to update the value of a OneToOneField from its default value (None), everything seems to work apart the fact that when I call save() the change is not written to the DB. 
Instead, if I change the value from the admin console everything works.

My models.py looks like this:

```
class Payment(m.Model):
    [stuff...]

class Order(m.Model):
    [stuff...]
    active = m.BooleanField(default = False)
    payment = m.OneToOneField(Payment, null = True, blank = True, on_delete=m.SET_NULL)
```

I have a function that activates the order, going like this:

```
def activate(self, ipn):
    [stuff..]
    self.payment = Payment(ipn = ipn)
    self.payment.save()
    self.active = True
    self.save()
```

After i call activate() on an order, the active value gets correctly set to True, but the payment value remains set to None. I can't figure out what is wrong. Any idea?

Ps: as i said, if i manually set the payment from the admin interface everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `payment_id` is set when you assign the `Payment` instance to `self.payment`. However, the `Payment` instance does not have an id at that point. You need to save it before you assign it to the `OneToOneField`.

```
def activate(self, ipn):
    [stuff..]
    payment = Payment(ipn = ipn)
    payment.save()
    self.payment = payment
    self.active = True
    self.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run your activate code in a shell you will probably see something like this:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "...." instance isn't saved in the database.
```

So basically firstly you need to create a `Payment` instance:

```
def activate(self, ipn):
    [stuff..]
    payment = Payment(ipn = ipn)
    payment.save()
    self.payment = payment
    self.active = True
    self.save()
```